# How to make ExceptAll ignore the slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have all the columns in the same table. I created below measure and made it ignore all slicers except date column. However, the slicers are still filtering it partially and I could not figure it out why.

I want the value of this measure not to be affected except by date slicer:

```
#_Measure= Calculate(SUM(Table1[Column]),ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[Date_Ownership]
))
```

Answer (score 0):

ALLEXCEPT will remove the filter from all columns in that ONE table, first argument, and EXCEPT the columns you specify. So you are removing the filtering from all columns on Table1 except Date_Ownership.
This does not apply to other tables.

With [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax) you can ignore other tables:

```
#_Measure =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[Column] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Date_Ownership] ),
    ALL(Table0),
    ALL(Table2)
)
```

All the Tables you don't want the filter to be in context.